# How do I read X and Y coordinates of a string in a File of type Word or Txt?

Tags: java, string, file

I would like to search for a string from a file of type Word or Text. After finding the searched string, I would like to get its location in the document (X and Y coordinates), atleast of the first characters of the searched string.

Example:
String to Search : "Test".

Contents of the File:

```
   ABCD EFGH
   This is a Test for Stackoverflow.
   Hello World.
```

I want to write a Java function that returns the position of T of the word "Test" as per the X and Y coordinates of that document.Or possibly Row and Column numbers? How do I do that?

I am able to search for the string using java.util.scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Row is a count of the number of line breaks you went through on your way to finding the word, and column is a count of the number of characters since the last line break that you went through on your way to finding the word.